# Visual Studio C# , DataGredView . Как мне считать значение "флажка"

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

Добавил я его в ручную,

```
//Datatable
DTS.Columns.Add("Удалить", typeof(bool));
```

Потом сделал её как источник данных для DataGredView

```
//DataGredView
dGVRSecond.DataSource = DTS;
```

Теперь я хочу считать значения с этого столбца, как я могу это сделать?

С изменением никаких проблем,

```
dGVRSecond.CurrentRow.Cells["Удалить"].Value =true;
```

а вот считать как?  пробовал нечто не подобии

```
bool Flag = (bool)dGVRSecond.CurrentRow.Cells["Удалить"].Value;
```

но компилятор ругается, нельзя так приводить говорит

Comment: Раз уж используется привязка данных, то следует работать с источником данных. Что-то вроде `(bool)DTS.Rows[rowIndex]["Удалить"]`

Comment: Нет, и так не приводит
`bool ch =(Boolean) DTS.Rows[dGVRSecond.CurrentRow.Index]["Удалить"] ;`

Короче посмотрел в дебагере чему равно поле при нажатом флажке, и пока-что такой костыль запилил

`bool ch = dGVRSecond.CurrentRow.Cells["Удалить"].Value.ToString()=="True";`